# UITableviewCell accessory Checkmark is not appearing in iphone5 and 5s

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I created a tableview with dynamic prototype cell.
I coded such that when user taps the cell accessory type should change to checkmark and when user selects again it should change to none. It is working fine in iPhone 6 and later series but not working in iPhone 5 and 5s.

Sample code in cellForRowAt indexPath

```
if let _ = selectedIndexPath {
            if (indexPath.compare(selectedIndexPath!) == .orderedSame) {
                if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                    cell.accessoryType = .none
                } else {
                    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: add code for cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the cell itself to tell you whether the checkmark is displayed; cells are reused so the accessory will reflect the *last* row that the cell was used for. I suggest you use a `Set<IndexPath>` to track which rows are checked.

Comment: Thank you for giving me suggestions. That was a pure mistake from my  side. I corrected it and working fine.